# Protecting a Chart Name

Tags: excel, vba

Does anyone know if there is a way to protect a chart name so that the user cannot change it? I've got quite a bit of code that references various charts. If a user was to change one or more of the chart names, things would get ugly in a hurry.

Comment: If I am not wrong then you have to protect the sheet for that

Comment: Why not use the chart index instead of a name.

Comment: @brettdj: Good Point! Honestly, that didn't even cross my mind :)

Comment: I don't trust indexes for the same reason that I don't use worksheet indexes. Indexes can change, but protected names can't. I think that I might just wind up protecting the worksheet. Thanks for the suggestion. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I might have a solution for you, but it brings some overhead.

You could add a *real* chart for every chart you are using and want to have name-protected in your workbook. They appear as seperate tabs (like a table) in your workbook.

Looks like here:

[image]

Right click on your chart and select *move chart* then *new sheet*. This way you are going to have "better" chart objects, which you can protect seperately through VBA or through Ribbon-Menue AND you have an internal **CodeName**!

Like here:

[image]

With an internal CodeName your user-troubles should be done with, because they can name them how they want and so can you ;) I don't trust indexes eighter and hate using user defined names - code names are the best, except for handling in code, but that is just a major vba flaw.

I'll guess, that those additional charts will however anoy you a bit, so just make them invisible and use copies of them as ChartObjects in your tables.

This should be it.

Further I stumbled uppon the interesting fact, that you really only can protect the chartname by protecting it as a nested object in a protected table. Even with my attempt users would be able to change the name, unless you protect the workbook-structure and all table/chart names with it.

Hope this helps ;)

Comment: Interesting idea. Thanks for the thought. I've sort of moved on from this project, and don't have time to get back to this. I appreciate you taking the time to think about this though!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this code.  Change "Sheet1" to "Chart#".  Also the last little bit (commented out & Workbook.Sheets.Count) can be added back in to your coding to add a incremental naming if you have many charts as you noted.

```
    ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(Sheets("Sheet2").CodeName).Name = "NewChartName" ' & Workbook.Sheets.Count
```